# Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\int_0^{\pi} xe^{-x\sin t}{\rm d}t=2$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

Someone gives a proof as follows：

> Above all, notice that \begin{align*} I(x):&=\int_0^{\pi} x{\rm  e}^{-x\sin t}{\rm d}t=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm e}^{-x\sin t}{\rm  d}t+\overbrace{\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} x{\rm e}^{-x\sin t}{\rm  d}t}^{t~ \mapsto ~t+\frac{\pi}{2}}\\ &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm  e}^{-x\sin t}{\rm d}t+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm e}^{-x\sin  \left(t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{\rm d}t\\ &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm e}^{-x\sin t}{\rm d}t+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm e}^{-x\cos t}{\rm  d}t\\ &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm e}^{-x\sin t}{\rm  d}t+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm e}^{-x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-  t\right)}{\rm d}t\\ &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm e}^{-x\sin t}{\rm
> d}t+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm e}^{-x\sin t}{\rm d}t\\
> &=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x{\rm e}^{-x\sin t}{\rm d}t. \end{align*}
>   Consider making a substitution that $\theta:=tx.$ Then $x=\theta/t,
>  {\rm d}\theta=x{\rm d}t.$ Thus $$I(x):=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi x}{2}}
>  \exp\left(-x\sin\frac{\theta}{x}\right){\rm d}\theta.$$ Since
>    $\theta/x \in[0,\pi/2],$ and $f(x):=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ decreases over
>    $(0,\pi/2]$, hence $ \sin \dfrac{\theta}{x}\ge \dfrac{2\theta}{\pi x}.$
>   Therefore $ -x\sin \dfrac{\theta}{x}\le -\dfrac{2\theta}{\pi },$ and
>    further we obtain $$\left|
> \exp\left(-x\sin\frac{\theta}{x}\right)\right|=
>  \exp\left(-x\sin\frac{\theta}{x}\right)\le \rm
>  e^{-\frac{2\theta}{\pi}},$$ the right hand side of which is integrable
>    over $ [0,+\infty) .$ Moreover $$\lim_{x \to
>  +\infty}\exp\left(-x\sin\frac{\theta}{x}\right)=\exp\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(\frac{\sin \frac{\theta}{x}}{\frac{\theta}{x}}\cdot -\theta\right)=e^{-\theta}.$$ Now, we can exchange the orders of the limit and the integral by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem and
>    obtain $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}I(x)=2\int_0^{+\infty}{\rm
>  e}^{-\theta}{\rm d}\theta=2.$$

**Is this correct? I don't know Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem well. Is there another proof more elementary?**

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: It is better to rewirte $I(x)$ as $$I(x):=2\int_0^\infty
 \exp\left(-x\sin\frac{\theta}{x}\right){\rm \chi_{\frac{\pi x}{2}}}(\theta)d\theta.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The proof in the OP is a standard way forward when equiped with the Dominated Convergence Theorem.  Herein, we present a way forward that relies on elementary calculus only and uses integration by parts.  To that end, we now proceed.

---

Let $I(x)$ be given by the integral

$$\begin{align}
I(x)&=\int_0^\pi xe^{-x\sin(t)}\,dt\\\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2} xe^{-x\sin(t)}\,dt\\\\
&=2\int_0^1 xe^{-x\sin(t)}\,dt+2\int_1^{\pi/2} xe^{-x\sin(t)}\,dt\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

As $x\to \infty$, it is evident that the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $0$ (since $\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x\sin(1)}=0$).

---

For the first integral, we integrate by parts with $u=\sec(t)$ and $v=-\frac1x e^{-x\sin(t)}\cos(t)$.  Proceeding we find that

$$\begin{align}
2\int_0^1 xe^{-x\sin(t)}\,dt&=2\left.\left(- \sec(t)e^{-x\sin(t)}\right)\right|_0^1+2\int_0^1 \sec(t)\tan(t)e^{-x\sin(t)}\,dt\\\\
&=2-2\sec(1)e^{-x\sin(1)}+2\int_0^1 \sec(t)\tan(t)e^{-x\sin(t)}\,dt\tag2
\end{align}$$

Letting $x\to\infty$ in $(2)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^\pi xe^{-x\sin(t)}\,dt=2$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Seeing $$2\int_0^1 xe^{-x\sin(t)}\,dt+2\int_1^{\pi/2} xe^{-x\sin(t)},$$  why the first does not tend to $0$? It's the same $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x\sin(1)}=0$.

Comment: It does not approach $0$ since at $t=0$, $\sin(t)=0$, and hence $e^{-x\sin(0)}=1$.  All of the "action" of this limit comes from integration near $t=0$.

Comment: +1 for the elementary approach (a regular feature in your answers).

Comment: @paramanandsingh Thank you.  Not all my answers are bases on elementary analysis

Comment: +1 does appear in my browser (will try to upvote again in case there is a problem) . And yes you also do a lot of complex analysis (my weak spot) but I tend to like these elementary ones

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I see the up vote now.  And thank you again my friend!  I hope that you're staying safe and healthy.

Comment: I am fine but to be frank in these difficult times MSE is the only source of enjoyment and hope left. Apart from this all online activity is mostly around Corona. Take care!

Comment: Pleased to hear that you're fine; sad to hear that MSE is your only source of hope. Take care too!

Comment: +1 from me. I can’t help to enjoy the beauty of an elementary calculus problem!

Comment: @taylorrendon Thank you.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ x>1 $ :

First of all, as you've shown : \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\,\mathrm{e}^{-x\sin{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x\,\mathrm{e}^{-x\sin{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}{x\,\mathrm{e}^{-x\sin{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t}\end{aligned}

Substituting $ t=\pi-y $ in the second term, we get : \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\,\mathrm{e}^{-x\sin{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t}=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x\,\mathrm{e}^{-x\sin{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t}\end{aligned}

Now substituting $ \small\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}y&=x\sin{t}\\ \mathrm{d}t&=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}}\end{aligned}\right. $, we get : \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\,\mathrm{e}^{-x\sin{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t}=2\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\end{aligned}

We have : \begin{aligned}\left|\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}-\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right|&=\left|\int_{x}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}-\int_{0}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}}\right)\mathrm{d}y}\right|\\ &=\left|\int_{x}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{y^{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right|\\ &\leq\int_{x}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{y^{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &\leq\int_{x}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{y^{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &\leq\int_{x}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{y^{2}}{\left(1+\frac{y^{2}}{2}\right)\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\end{aligned}

(We used the fact that $ \mathrm{e}^{y}\geq 1+y+\frac{y^{2}}{2}\geq 1+\frac{y^{2}}{2} $ then we took its inverse)

Now since the integral we got can be computed, $ \int_{0}^{x}{\frac{y^{2}}{\left(1+\frac{y^{2}}{2}\right)\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}}\,\mathrm{d}y}=\pi x\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}}}\right) $, we get that : $$ \left|\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}-\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right|\leq\int_{x}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}+\frac{\pi}{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}}}\right)\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

Which means $$ \int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}=1 $$

Hence $$ \int_{0}^{\pi}{x\,\mathrm{e}^{-x\sin{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t}\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}2 $$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\expo{-x\sin\pars{t}}\dd t & =
\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}x\expo{-x\cos\pars{t}}\dd t =
2\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\expo{-x\cos\pars{t}}\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
2\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\expo{-x\sin\pars{t}}\dd t =
2\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}x\expo{-xt}\dd t
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & =
2\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\dd t = \bbx{\large 2}
\end{align}
In line (\ref{1}), I used the
[Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).